# Check for Header/Column name in Excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am iterating over many CSV files having header/ Column name in each and every CSV file,  and then putting data into a single Excel file . But every time the header / Column name gets copied in to Excel file although it gets copied in new line only, but the thing is, I only need header / Column Name only once into excel file.

FYI I am using Pandas to_excel() function to put data into the Excel file.

Thanks in Advance.

This is my Code:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/home/viral/Testing"
def __init__(self):
    self.observer = Observer()

def run(self):
    event_handler = Handler()
    self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
    self.observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
    except:
        self.observer.stop()
        print("Error")

    self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

@staticmethod
def on_any_event(event):
    if event.is_directory:
        return None

    elif event.event_type == 'created':
        # Take any action here when a file is first created.
        print("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)
        df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0)
        append_df_to_excel('/home/viral/myfile.xlsx', df, index = False)
        # all_data = pd.read_excel('/home/viral/myfile.xls')
        # combined = all_data.append(new_data)
        # combined.to_excel('myfile.xlsx', header = False)

    elif event.event_type == 'modified':
        # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
        print("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)

@staticmethod
def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                   truncate_sheet=False,
                   **to_excel_kwargs):
                   # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

# Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist
    try:
        FileNotFoundError
    except NameError:
        FileNotFoundError = IOError


    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
    # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 0
    #if ((pd.read_excel(filename).column) is None):
        # write out the new sheet

        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)
    #else:
        #df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs, header=None)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Comment: Can you specify 1) what is the input 2) what is expected v current output?

Comment: @patrick Answer -1 ) Input is multiple csv files and I am iterating over each at a time. Answer - 2 ) I want the data from every csv file into one excel file. But header should be written only once into my Excel file as each of my csv file is having header/ column name and I don't want those column names again and again into my excel file. I hope you got my point ?

Comment: viral, thanks makes sense. let me think

Comment: I tried this but didn't worked :

if ((pd.read_excel(filename).column) is None):
            # write out the new sheet
            
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)
        else:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs, header=None)

Answer (score 0):

The information is somewhat limited, but the below would do the trick. Instead of  manually setting up the `csv1`, `csv2` dataframes, you would obviously read them e.g. with `read_csv`.

If this is not what you are looking for, pls post your current code for more info.

```
import pandas

cols = ["colname1", "colname2", "colname3"]
vals1 = [[1],[2],[3]]
vals2 = [[1000, 10000],[2000, 6000],[3000, 4000]]
csv1 = pandas.DataFrame({k:v for k,v in zip(cols, vals1)})
print(csv1)
csv2 = pandas.DataFrame({k:v for k,v in zip(cols, vals2)})
print(csv2)
outputdf = pandas.concat([csv1, csv2])
print(outputdf)
outputdf.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Code Posted into my Original Post

Comment: Code is now available !